# Operating on ArrayList of ArrayList to format data and show in a recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

This is an advanced data manipulation of sorting and showing the data. I have an array list of objects let's say

```
 ArrayList<PersonDetails> personList= new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(name:"George",date:"25-DEC-2019",duration:"30mins",time:"9:45",slot:"Morning",exercise-type:"Leg-Exercise");
personList.add(name:"Ramesh",date:"25-DEC-2019",duration:"30mins",slot:"9:45","Morning",exercise-type:"Leg-Exercise");
personList.add(name:"Joslin",date:"25-DEC-2019",duration:"30mins",slot:"9:45","Morning",exercise-type:"Arms-Exercise");
personList.add(name:"Hrithik",date:"25-DEC-2019",duration:"30mins",slot:"9:45","Morning",exercise-type:"Arms-Exercise");
```

all data type are string.so, I have to operate on this list and show the final result something like this on a recyclerview. I want to group persons which have the same exercise type and there individual in one object. also I want to count the person who has the same exercise type.

```
Details
-----------------------------------------------------
Exercise-type               Leg-exercise
Person                  2
-----------------------------------------------------
George                  
Date                    25-Dec-2019
Duration                30mins
Time                    9:45
Slot                    Morning

Ramesh
Date                    25-Dec-2019
Duration                30mins
Time                    9:45
Slot                    Morning

Details
-----------------------------------------------------
Exercise-type               Arms-exercise
Person                  2
-----------------------------------------------------
Joslin                  
Date                    25-Dec-2019
Duration                30mins
Time                    9:45
Slot                    Morning

Hrithik                     
Date                    25-Dec-2019
Duration                30mins
Time                    9:45
Slot                    Morning
```

This is my **item_detail_order.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/fieldItems"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_item_key"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium_0"
        android:text="detail_items"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBody">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_item_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold_0"
        android:text="detail_values">

    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here the id - **detail_item_key** is for example the name or duration, or slot,etc.
and the id -  **detail_item_value**is for example the corresponding value from the name,duration and slot.

**DetailObjectAdapter.java**

```
public class DetailsObjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailsObjectAdapter.DetailsObjectViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<DetailsObject> detailsObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DetailsObjectAdapter(ArrayList<DetailsObject> detailsList) {
        detailsObjectList = detailsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DetailsObjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_summary, parent, false);

        return new DetailsObjectViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DetailsObjectViewHolder holder, int position) {

        DetailsObject detailsObject = detailsObjectList.get(position);
        holder.detailsItemKey.setText(detailsObject.getNamekey());
        holder.detailsItemValue.setText(detailsObject.getNameValue());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return detailsObjectList.size();
    }

    public class DetailsObjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.detail_item_key)
        TextView detailsItemKey;

        @BindView(R.id.detail_item_value)
        TextView detailsItemValue;

        public DetailsObjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried grouping the exercise-type with hashmap but it will result in a whole new string. which then I have to manipulate it line by line. Which I don't generally prefer.
**I really don't want you all to write the whole code for me. Just a way to tell me exactly how to approach this? like a pseudo code.or something?**

**DetailsObject.java**

```
public class DetailsObject {
    String namekey;



    public DetailsObject(String namekey, String nameValue) {
        this.namekey = namekey;
        this.nameValue = nameValue;
    }

    public String getNameValue() {
        return nameValue;
    }

    public String getNamekey() {
        return namekey;
    }

    String nameValue;
}
```

Comment: you have to add two checks first for exercise and second for date.create two separate list one for exercise and second for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new `HashMap < String, ArrayList < Details Object > >`. Segregate the list of object of a type into a List and add to this HashMap using the key Exercise type. 
When you have to show this data in a recyclerview you can make two viewholders one will show the Exercise header and count of the people and other will show details of the people.

Follow examples like [these](https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e) to generate a single list that will be passed to your recycler view Adapter.

Comment: should'nt the second parameter be PersonDetails in the hashmap? You mean the Detail Object to be the complete list of all the Objects right? I've updated the question with DetailedObject java file.

Comment: No the list will contain only contain the personDetails which have same type of exercise

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you have to add two checks first for exercise and second for date.
Create two separate list one for exercise and second for data.

```
ArrayList<String> exerciseType=new ArrayList()

ArrayList<String> dateList=new ArrayList()
```

now add all exercises in arrrayList but do add **contains** check to avoid duplicate entries same for date.
now use loop and create a separate array for each exercise and save them to `HashMap<String,ArrayList<DetailModel>> exerciseArrays=new HashMap()`